# elmah.mvc remote access, what should be set?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, elmah, elmah.mvc

elmah.mvc should work with mvc5 smoothly?

To rule out any other problem, I created a new Web mvc project (with VS2015).
I added with nuget the Elmah.mvc package, and the configuration looks like this:

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="super" />  
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
```

From what I gathered documentation, that all that is needed to enable the user which have the `super` role, to access elmah page remotaly.

But when i publish to server, and i try access http://mysite/elmah page, if i not logged so I redicated to login page.
but after login as a user with the role requried, i get:
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Comment: Could you post your entire web.config?

Answer (score 1):

```
<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1"/>
</elmah>
```

It solved the problem (i.e: the elmha page accessible for user with the specified role). But that's not mentioned in the `elmah.mvc` documentation.